# How to summarize a list of serial numbers that have the same test result

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have serialized parts that are sent out for testing.  These serials are assigned to a "container" which is associated to a shop order number.  This was all tracked manually on paper and I want to create a report, using SSRS Report Builder, by shop order that shows the container and the associated serial numbers. I am grouping by the container number, showing the list of serials, whether they passed or failed and then displaying the count of serial numbers.  I have managed to do all this, but the report is dozens of pages long.  I want to summarize all the sequential serial numbers that have the same status on one row showing the first serial number and the last serial number.  The next row will have the summarized sequential list of serials that has a different status.  And, so on and so forth.  While doing this, I still need to display the count of serials in that container.

[image: Current Query Results]

[image: Future (Desired) Query Results]

(Unfortunately, my current status on this website only allows me to attach images.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not tagged your question with the version of SQL Server you are using, I'm assuming it's a fairly recent version here...

Doing this in SSRS will be tricky so this is how I would approach it. Other may come up with a much more elegant way but if not, at least you have this solution...

I replicated your dataset in  table variable, then derived a column that checks if the previous record with the same `ShopOrder`, `ContNumber`, and `TestResult` has a serial number one less than the current one.

It then wrapped this in a query that add a 'Batch' number by doing a running sum of this derived column. Finally I get the MIN and MAX value with each batch and CONCAT these in a string for final output.

The code looks like this...

DECLARE @t TABLE (ShopOrder varchar(10), ContNumber varchar(10), SerialNo int, TestResult varchar(10))

```
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13352  , 'Accept'),
    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13353  , 'Accept'),
    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13354  , 'Accept'),
    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13355  , 'Accept'),
    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13356  , 'Accept'),
    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13357  , 'Accept'),

    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13359  , 'Accept'),
    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13360  , 'Reject'),
    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13361  , 'Accept'),
    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13362  , 'Accept'),
    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13363  , 'Accept'),
    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13364  , 'Accept'),
    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13365  , 'Reject'),
    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13366  , 'Accept'),
    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13367  , 'Accept'),
    ('ABC13-A', 'CONT-A', 13368  , 'Accept')

--

SELECT DISTINCT
    ShopOrder, ContNumber
    , SerialNos = IIF(
                    MIN(SerialNo) OVER(PARTITION BY Batch) = Max(SerialNo) OVER(PARTITION BY Batch)
                    , CONCAT('',MIN(SerialNo) OVER(PARTITION BY Batch))
                    , CONCAT(MIN(SerialNo) OVER(PARTITION BY Batch), ' - ', Max(SerialNo) OVER(PARTITION BY Batch))
                    )
    , TestResult
    , RecCount = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Batch)
    FROM (
            SELECT 
                    *
                    , Batch = SUM(IsFirstSerial) OVER(ORDER BY RowN)
                FROM 
                    (
                    SELECT 
                            *
                            , IsFirstSerial = IIF(LAG(RowN, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY ShopOrder, ContNumber, TestResult ORDER BY RowN) = RowN - 1, 0,1)
                        FROM (SELECT *, RowN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SerialNo) FROM @t) a 
                    ) x
    ) z
```

The final output looks like this, I'm not sure how you are counting the records but a record count for each batch is also supplied.

[image]

Comment: This looks like it would work, but, as you noticed, there may be times when there will be a missing serial number, if it was rejected at another earlier operation.  Thanks, Alan.

Comment: Maybe add a ROW_NUMBER by serial no and use that instead of the serial to overcome the missing issue? I was trying to use RANK on the raw data to make it work. :(

Comment: I was thinking the same when I was writing it Hannover, I'll edit the question later and include a row_number to resolve this issue. @David Lopez I'll post an update to the answer as soon as I get time.

Comment: I've edited the answer so it now handles the missing Serial correctly

Comment: Perfect!! Tested different scenarios and came up with the expected results.